# Valutazione di un lavoro scolastico

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, nouns

Quale vocabolo si usa per designare la valutazione che fa un insegnante di un esame o di un lavoro scolastico? Nei dizionari ho trovato "voto", ma non so se questa è la parola che veramente si usa in tutti gli ambiti scolastici.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tradizionalmente si usa(va) **voto** per valori numerici (6, 4, 9 etc.), e **giudizio** per espressioni come "buono", "insufficiente", "scarso", "ottimo" etc.

Poi naturalmente non ci sono regole eccessivamente rigide, quindi uno studente a cui l'insegnante ha dato un "ottimo" potrebbe dire "ho preso un bel|buon voto", anche se un po' impropriamente, e si capirebbe ugualmente senza problemi.

C'è anche un termine più generico come **valutazione** (o "valutazione di merito") con cui ci si può riferire tanto a un voto come a un giudizio, e con il contesto, nel caso ce ne sia bisogno, si può chiarire di cosa si stia parlando esattamente.